# Mongoose not sorting number properly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a issue in mongodb number sorting using mongoose.

My data look like `50,3000,75,42000,400,100` :

```json
[
  {"date":"2015-10-09 16:42:50","price":"700","item":"Milk"},
  {"date":"2016-08-04 00:46:13","price":"60","item":"Bread"},
  {"date":"2016-06-14 20:42:49","price":"50","item":"Soap"}
]
```

When I sort by numbers in desc order, it result in `75,50,42000,400,3000,100`.

I was expecting `42000,3000,100,75,50`.

My code

```json
Orders.find({order_type:'buy',status:'instock'})
    .sort([['price', 'desc']])
    .limit(10)
    .exec(function(e, data){

});
```

Comment: Looks like it sorted by alphabetical order, are you sure `price` is a array of numbers?

Comment: yes, here is the sample data
[{"date":"2015-10-09 16:42:50","price":"700","item":"Milk"},{"date":"2016-08-04 00:46:13","price":"60","item":"Bread"},{"date":"2016-06-14 20:42:49","price":"50","item":"Soap"}]

Comment: I was talking about the mongoose / mongoDB schema.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that, as indicated by your data:

```
{
    "date":"2015-10-09 16:42:50",
    "price":"700", //Notice the " around the price
    "item":"Milk"
}
```

`price` is stored not as a number, but as a string.

You should either edit your source data and/or your Mongoose model, or get the data unsorted, convert the price to numbers, and then sort.

```
{
    date: {type: String},
    price: {type: String},
    item: {type: Number}
}
```

Also ensure that, when you import your data inside mongoDB, they are treated as number. When you print the data, the content of `price` should not have any `"` around it.

Comment: Price change String to Number in model schema , but result is same.

Comment: Is your model like the one I posted? Did you reimport the data?

Comment: in mongodb console, it showing like this "price" : "37000", what i do now?
I have a existing sql file, how to import into mongodb?

Comment: It mean `price` is seen as a string. You need to convert `price` to a number, either in the sql, or in mongoDB. But this is beyond the scope of the current question.

Comment: Thanks @DrakaSan, its working fine after doing this 
`code` db.orders.find({'order_type':'buy','status':'instock'}).forEach( function (x) {
  x.price = parseInt(x.price); 
  db.orders.save(x);
});